# Perform a function after a set time

Tags: javascript

I want to perform a certain function using Javascript after 2000ms

```
document.querySelector('[name="4109~~0~0~0~18291930$txtValue"]').value = 'APPLE';
```

For this I have set the code as:

```
function fireTheSubmitEvent() {
 setTimeout(fireTheSubmitEvent, 2000)
 
  document.querySelector('[name="4109~~0~0~0~18291930$txtValue"]').value = 'APPLE';
  }
```

But it is not firing. Where am I going wrong?. Please guide.

Comment: Put the `setTimeout` *outside* the function, or it'll never be called

Comment: Thanks , This solved my querry. Corrected code is ```function fireTheSubmitEvent() {

 
  document.querySelector('[name="4109~~0~0~0~18291930$txtValue"]').value = 'APPLE';
  }```
   setTimeout(fireTheSubmitEvent, 2000)